# How can I retrieve logs from Android client application after publish?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-log

I have an android app that is continuously talking to a Google app engine through endpoints.
Is there some way to fetch the error logs dumped on client machine directly or should I create another end point for the same?

Comment: These error logs appear in your admin console, under "monitoring" no?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use ACRA (http://www.acra.ch/), it automatically will send you error reports when crushing the app and you can as well force the app to send error logs. I understand you are expecting to perform the second one and looking for automatic LogCat information when an error occurs.